# Does V have a model that looks like V, according to Morse-Kelly set theory?

Tags: logic, set-theory, model-theory, meta-math, provability

Let's talk about V, the class of all sets. We can't talk about this in ZFC, of course, so we will use [Morse-Kelly set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse%E2%80%93Kelley_set_theory) instead, which has classes.

My question is, can Morse-Kelly set theory prove (or disprove!) that their exists a model (U, $\in_U$) of set theory (where $U$ is a set, and therefore $(U, \in_U) \in V$) such that (V, $\in$) and (U, $\in_U$) are [elementary equivalent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_equivalence) as models of set theory?

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  MK can define the satisfaction relation for $(V,\in)$ (and more generally for class models), and so it can carry out the usual proof of downward Löwenheim-Skolem for $(V,\in)$ (using global choice to get Skolem functions).  This produces a countable elementary submodel $(U,\in_U)\prec (V,\in)$.

Alternatively, if you just want a structure that is elementarily equivalent to $(V,\in)$, since MK can define satisfaction in $(V,\in)$ it can define the theory of $(V,\in)$ and knows that this theory is consistent.  The first-order completeness theorem now shows the theory of $(V,\in)$ has a (set) model.

Comment: Cool! Would this imply that there is $(T, \epsilon_T) \in U$ equivalent to $U$, and so in an infinite descending sequence? Or would non-absoluteness kill that?

Comment: Also, since the $U$ you constructed is countable, what would the strength of an oracle (in the context of computability) for $(U, \epsilon_U)$ be like?

Comment: For your first question, I think no.  The problem isn't absoluteness but first-orderness.  The statement "$(U,\in_U)$ is an elementary submodel of the universe" cannot be expressed by a single formula in the language of set theory, since truth in the universe is not definable (it is only definable over the larger language where you can refer to classes).  So the existence of such a $(U,\in_U)$ need not be preserved in an elementary submodel.  For your second question, I have no idea.

Comment: Okay. Could we specifically construct a model $(U, \epsilon_U)$ so that it has an infinite descending chain of models though?

Comment: An infinite descending chain of models $U_0\ni U_1\ni U_2\dots$ would violate regularity, at least assuming you can prove the collection of all of them is a set.

Comment: Well technically it would be $V \ni U_0 \ni_{U_0} U_1 \ni_{U_1} U_2 \ni_{U_2} \dots$.

Comment: @PyRulez: But Löwenheim-Skolem produces an elementary _submodel_, so $\in_{U_0}$ is a restriction of the ordinary $\in$.

Comment: If you're not requiring your models to have the usual element relation, then all sorts of crazy things can happen.  For instance, ZFC proves that if T is any consistent extension of ZFC, then there is a countable model $(M,\in_M)$ of T which has an element $(N,\in_N)$ which is itself isomorphic to $(M,\in_M)$ (and so by iterating this you get an infinite chain).  See Lemmas 5 and 7 of https://arxiv.org/abs/1104.4450v1.  In particular, MK proves this for T the first-order theory of the universe.

Comment: @PyRulez: If you are looking for just elementarily equivalent models (not elementary submodels) and you don't ask for $\in$ to be the standard membership, then the existence of these chains follows by a straightforward compactness argument: by the argument cited by this answer, MK shows that for any finite $A\subseteq \operatorname{Th}(V)$, $V$ shows that $A$ is satisfiable. That is a first-order statement, and by compactness, there is a countable model in $V$ with the same theory as $V$ itself, and you can do the same internally in there.

Comment: With standard membership that is impossible without violating either choice or regularity.